# Strange reproducible behaviour with Remove - Characters not being removed correctly

Tags: c#, string

I am experiencing very strange behaviour using the Remove method of a string.

```
    public static Boolean StartsWithCommand(String lineIn, out String lineOut, String command)
    {
        String correctedLine = lineIn.Trim();
        String correctedCommand = command.Trim();
        if (correctedLine.ToLower().StartsWith(correctedCommand.ToLower()) == true)
        {
            lineOut = correctedLine.Remove(0, correctedCommand.Length);
            return true;
        }
        lineOut = lineIn;
        return false;
    }
```

Very simply, I check if a trimmed string (command) is at the start of a second trimmed string (lineIn). If so, I output lineIn to lineOut with the command removed, otherwise just output lineIn. Yet consider the test:

```
        String testString = "0123456789";
        StartsWithCommand(testString, out testString, "0123");
        //testString should be 456789, yet I get 23456789
```

I've searched MSDN for anything regarding the Remove function but there's nothing to indicate any issues. Running this through a debugger I can confirm that correctedCommand.Length is of the correct length (4), but only two characters are being removed. What could the cause of this be?

Comment: Do **not** delete all of your content and say your "editing for clarity" *ever*.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Explain the correct procedure then.

Comment: You just make the edits in place... As of right now, you have a post that can immediately be flagged for being low quality.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Leaving the question up likewise seems a rather wrong way of doing things, allowing people to answer a question which is being edited for clarity.

Comment: should just hit the delete button, edit it, then undelete it to save yourself from getting bunch downvotes

Comment: @Steve I wasn't aware I was able to undelete a question... Shall do that then. Thanks for the feedback. To be quite frank, downvoting a question that has been changed for "Editing for clarity" is at best non-sensical and worst idiotic.

Comment: And how are people supposed to look at it now? There is nothing to answer at all. If your question was so unclear that you need to remove all content in order to fix it, seems like you might as well delete it and post a clarified version (although I'm  not 100% sure that the best option). Anyone who comes in and sees a question like this is likely going to downvote immediately.

Comment: you are using StartsWithCommand1 instead of StartsWithCommand....Works fine on my machine BTW

Comment: @Steve Thank you, an error in typing, pasting wasn't working too well!

Comment: Are you using code other that that code you've posted? With `"0123456789"`, `"0123456789"`, and `"0123"` passed as arguments, the code works as expected.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Yes, exactly.

Comment: I would suggest making a brand new empty project, and pasting *only* the code you've posted *exactly* as it is here and seeing what happens. I would kind of be surprised if there was some kind of overlooked bug like this in `Remove`, so I've got to assume some other code is impacting the result in some way that is unclear.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb There was no other code present, but solution has been found. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

There is no issue within the code, the problem was far more subtle. For reasons unknown and a situation I've never seen before, the string that was being passed in (`testString`), had a byte order mark at the start of it. This was never shown in any text editors, and was only realised after showing the integer value of each character of the `teststring`. Copying and pasting this particular string would always copy and paste the BOM - so the error was always carried over.

Hope this helps somebody else who may have a similar issue.